# Simple math logic question: $A$ is $B$ if $C$, $A$ is $B$ if $D$ then $C \Leftrightarrow D$?

Tags: logic, proof-verification

Suppose that $A$ is $B$ if $C$, $A$ is $B$ if $D$ then $C \Leftrightarrow D$?

Full context: I am looking over something which stated

**Definition**: a matrix $A$ is "Hurwitz-Cantor" if condition $C$ is satisfied.

Then it follows by Theorem:

A matrix $A$ is "Hurwitz-Cantor" if $D$ is satisfied.

**Then somewhere in a proof much later on, the authors seem to assert that: Since $D$ is satisfied, therefore $A$ is Hurwitz-Cantor, and thus $C$ is satisfied.**

To me, the logic is off. Can anyone check?

Comment: Your final symbolization of $C$ if, and only if $D$ doesn't work because they are independent properties that must be satisfied for $A$ to be equivalent to $B$.  If you want to use an iff (if, and only if) operator you need to show that $C$ and $D$ are necessary, but not sufficient alone for $A$ to equal $B$.  If you know that $A$ is $B$, then you already know $C$ and $D$ are satisfied, because both are necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a definition of a qualifying adjective, "if" usually really means "if and only if".

But it looks like your condition $D$ is only sufficient, not necessary. So I would say that $D\implies C$, but not necessarily that $C\implies D$.

Comment: Oh my. I never knew about this. Yes, in the definition it specifically writes Def: A is "..." if condition C is satisfied. I had no idea it would be an iff

Comment: Well, just think about it. If I say a person is called a criminal if he has committed a crime, then each person who has committed a crime is a criminal and each person who has not committed a crime is not a criminal. It isn't the case that there are criminals who have not committed a crime. So, implicitly, I really mean that a person is a criminal if and only if he has committed a crime. The word "if" in ordinary English usage can have various real meanings, you just have to understand the intention, not the literal use. English is not mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that $D\implies A$ is a theorem. On the other hand, the statement $C \implies A$ is a *definition*, hence $C\iff A$. Thus, when the author states "$D$, therefore $A$", since $A\iff C$, we also have $C$.

Strictly speaking, if all we had was $D\implies A$, and $C\implies A$, we could not necessarily conclude $C\iff D$. To be concrete, take the two statements (1) If it's raining, then I'm wet, and (2) If I am swimming, then I'm wet. It should be clear that we don't get the equivalence of the two premises.

Comment: Why did you make $A$ the consequent in your conditionals?

Comment: @floorcat I guess imagine that $A$ stands for "A matrix $A$ is Hurwitz-Cantor"... I don't really have any good reason for choosing $A$.

Comment: I think your answer is intuitively correct, but my impression is that (using OP terms) you would say that $A$ is the antecedent which leads to the consequent $B$, of being the Hurwitz-Cantor.  But while writing this I reread the OP, and it seems $B$ isn't really necessary in the OP itself...

Comment: Unless $A$ is to be an arbitrary matrix, and $B$ the property of a Hurwitz-Cantor matrix.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you confused a definition for a claim. I would often see definitions written in the form "A is B if and only if C", which simply means "If C, we would say A is B". The form "A is B if C" in a **definition** is just another way to put it.